# Audio does not play on keyboard event with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a key (s) that I want to press in order to create a keyboard event which would be a sound that I have linked in my file. The sound src is correct, and from what I know, so is my JavaScript. Is there a step that I am not aware of for adding sound in a HTML file?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-12">
                    <div data-key="83" class="key">
                        <kbd>s</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">clap</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <audio data-key="83" src="jap/big_taiko.wav"></audio>



        <script>
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
                const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
                if (!audio) return;
                audio.play();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using inverted ticks `` ` `` instead of single `'` quotes for string interpolation. Use the following selector:

`` `audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]` ``

Comment: Thank you this did the trick. May I ask why this is? I was completely unaware of inverted ticks in JavaScript.

Comment: @YoungCoder, single quotation marks `'` or double quotation marks `"` do not evaluate your variables & treat them as a part of the string. Back-ticks, however, were introduced to solve the issue with the mess caused by complex string concatenation. Compare:

`'start' + a + 'middle' + b + 'endstring'` vs ` `id${a}middle${b}endstring` `.
You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.addEventListener` instead of `window.addEventListener`.

Also i changed querySelector `audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]` with `'audio[data-key="'+e.keyCode+'"]'`

```js
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { 
     const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="'+e.keyCode+'"]');
                if (!audio) return;
                audio.play();
            });
```

```html
  <audio data-key="83" src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3"></audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that the problem is in this line:

```
const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
```

The $ notation to replace variables in a string works with ` not ' but this is ES6 notation, both the keyword const and the `.

```
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

or the ES5 version

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="' + e.keyCode +'"]');
```